# Python call class method with argument

Tags: python, class

I have a class say:

```
class MyClass:
    def mymethod(self, data1, data2):
        print (self.data1)
        print (self.data2)
```

and I am calling this class somewhere in a Django view and sending this argument like:

```
mycls = MyClass()
mycls.mymethod(data1, data2)
```

When I do this it says 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'data1'

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't assigned to them yet. I'm guessing that what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def mymethod(self, data1, data2):
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2
        print(self.data1)
        print(self.data2)
```

Until you actually assign to `self.something` (even if you have a parameter to the method called `something`), that variable doesn't exist. `something` and `self.something` are two different things.

Or, if you're just trying to print the values of two parameters to a method, you might want to do this instead:

```
class MyClass:
    def mymethod(self, data1, data2):
        print(data1)
        print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

in `MyClass.mymethod` you totally ignore the `data1` and `data2` args and try to print the (obviously non-existant) instance attributes `self.data1` and `self.data2`. Either it's a typo (yeah, it happens ) or you don't understand what is `self` in this context and the difference between arguments and attributes...

Answer (score 0):

try this data1 you are sending and in mymethod are different :

```
class MyClass:
    def mymethod(self, data1, data2):
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2
        print self.data1
        print self.data2
```

OR

```
         print data1
         print data2
```